# CSS: Ignore property in nested class

Tags: css

I'm facing an issue while setting the padding for the class `code` in CSS. I'm using `code` for code inline and `highlight` for code blocks. The problem is that the second inherits from the former and shows extra padding on the first line. Is there a way to avoid inheriting from code in .highlight for that specific property?

```
code {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0470588);
  font-family: Menlo, Monaco, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: .2em .4em;
  background-color: rgba(27,31,35,.05);
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline

}

.highlight {
  background: #282a36;
  color: #f8f8f2;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 4pt;
  padding: 8pt;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: block;
}
```

I want to remove the padding before the first `git`, but keep it when I format something inline, like `master`:

[image]

The problem is that the generated HTML includes a `code` label as well:

```
<p><strong>This release candidate would the one potentially being shipped to iTunes Connect</strong>. 
In case the final testing and the review process would be satisfactory, the app would be published and a manual merge from release into <code>master</code> would be made, <strong>including a tag with the version number. 
The <code>master</code> branch would ideally contain all the app versions published in the AppStore, properly tagged.</strong></p>

<pre class="highlight shell"><code>git checkout master
git tag v.1.2          <span class="c"># As an example</span>
git push <span class="nt">--tags</span>
</code></pre>
```

Comment: Have you tried with specificity `code.highlight {`

Comment: Yes, but makes no difference. Playing with the browser inspector the only way to get rid of it seems to disable the padding property in the code class.

Comment: Could you please add the corresponding HTML and specify the desired result?

Comment: I added the missing HTML. I see the problem now, the <pre> block contains a <code> label as well... so I'm not sure if I can get rid of the padding in case I'm in a <pre> block...

Comment: How about selecting pre > code and disable the padding?

Comment: `p > code` would do it in that exact case, but you might also want to create something even more specific. What can you control / not control in the markup?

Comment: `pre code { padding: 0pt; }`

Does work :-)